# Mass hanging from spring: potential energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, energy, potential, spring

I have encountered a problem with a mass $m$ hanging from a spring. I want to find the maximum distance it will be stretched from the spring's equilibrium. At the maximum distance the spring is stretched, the mass will be at rest so the weight will cancel out the spring force, so we should have,

$$ky = mg$$

or

$$y = \frac{mg}{k}$$

Where $k$ is the spring constant, $y$ is the maximum distance, $m$ is the mass and $g$ is gravitational acceleration. But, if you look at this problem through the conservation of energy, you would conclude energy is conserved, since we have only a spring force and gravity acting. If we define our origin to be the spring's equilibrium, then the initial energy of the system is zero. The energy at all other times must be zero, so at maximum distance, we have,

$$\frac{ky^2}{2} + mg(-y) = 0$$

Which yields a different answer of

$$y = \frac{2mg}{k}$$

What's going on? Where am I going wrong in approaching this problem?

Comment: At the maximum distance the spring is indeed stretched, but the mass is not at rest. And the weight won't cancel out the spring force.

Comment: @StephenWong, at maximum distance, the mass is at rest by definition.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Ok, I was wrong, the mass is at rest, its velocity is zero, but its acceleration isn't zero because of it is subjected to gravity and spring force. And then the mass will accelerate toward to its equilibrium position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's going on? Where am I going wrong in approaching this problem?

Carefully consider your 3rd statement:

> At the maximum distance the spring is stretched, the mass will be at
>   rest so the weight will cancel out the spring force

At maximum distance, the mass will certainly be at rest but is it necessarily true that the weight and spring force *cancel*?

Put another way, does that fact that an object is (instantaneously) at rest imply that the *acceleration* of the object is *zero*?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Makes perfect sense. I was misled into thinking for some reason at rest in this case meant zero acceleration, when it just means zero velocity.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that if the net force at a point is zero, we can only claim that the acceleration at that point is zero, it doesn't imply that the velocity at that point is zero as well. So when you release the block from it's natural length, it will fall down by mg/k, in the process of which it will acquire some velocity, and then continue moving downwards until it's Kinetic Energy is zero. For a block to be at rest, the necessary condition is that it shall have zero velocity, and not zero acceleration. As an example take the case of uniform motion in one dimension, it has zero acceleration( as constant velocity) , but still it isn't at rest. For a block to be at rest, it MUST have zero velocity.