# Spring mass vertical extension

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, spring, equilibrium

consider a vertical spring which is initially free. We are attaching a mass to its end and is allowed to extend gradually. When we apply force balance at this equilibrium position , [K.x= M.g] Therefore x=M.g/K

Now if we apply energy conservation , [ 0.5 K.x^2 =M.g.x ]  Therefore x= 2 M.g/K

why the value of x is coming out to be different in both case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mass hanging from spring: potential energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/221720/)

Comment: To make the spring extend gradually you have to hold the mass to support it while you gradually lower it, and that means the weight of the mass does work on you. That's where the energy goes.

Comment: I thought this problem for a while... Potential energy  drop of mass = Spring Potential energy+ Energy lost to dissipative forces(if it comes to rest after we  drop the mass from one end of spring)................Now if there is no dissipative forces like air drag the mass will oscillate continuosly and will never settle ....now if we are slowly lowering the mass and helping it to reach new equilibrium,then.... Potential energy change= spring potential energy+[work done by mass on hand given by integrating (Mg-Kx)dx]...am i right??

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir....

Answer (score 0):

Because the second case does not describe the equilibrium. When you attach the mass, it goes down beyond the equilibrium position until the kinetic energy that the mass has at the equilibrium position transforms into the potential energy of the spring. If there is damping in the system, the mass eventually will come to equilibrium, but then it will have lower mechanical energy than at the beginning.