# How to determine the extension of a spring?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy-conservation, spring

[image]

The spring extended by $x\ m$, and the object moved downward from the mean position due to the force of gravity and reached an equilibrium. Find $x$.

**My attempt:**

I used a free body diagram to find $x$:

[image]

$$Mg=kx \tag{i}$$

$$\implies x=\frac{Mg}{k}\tag{1}$$

**My instructor's attempt:**

By the conservation of mechanical energy,

$$K_f+U_f=K_i+U_i$$

$$\text{, where $K_f$=final kinetic energy of the system, $U_f$=final potential energy of the system, $K_i$=initial kinetic energy of the system, $U_i$=initial potential energy of the system}$$

$$0+\frac{1}{2}kx^2-Mgx=0+0 \tag{ii}$$

$$\implies x=\frac{2Mg}{k}\tag{2}$$

(1) and (2) are not the same. Why?

Comment: In your force calculation (under the influence of the spring force and the gravity force alone), at the equilibrium position, the kinetic energy isn't zero. (In the conservation of energy calculation, the final condition has kinetic energy zero.)

Comment: Incidentally, the same question is answered here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/221720/mass-hanging-from-spring-potential-energy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You and your teacher are solving two different problems.

[image]

1. **You** You are calculating the equilibrium position of the mass: this is the point of zero net force where the weight of the mass, $mg$ matches the force of the extended spring, $kx$. The result is $$x_0 = \frac{mg}{k}$$ and is correct.
2. **Your teacher** The teaches attaches the mass to the free spring (position $A$) and lets it fall. Then the teacher calculates the *maximum* extension of the spring, i.e., the lowest point in will reach before bouncing back. We can do this by energy balance: the potential energy of the mass in $A$ is $mg x'$, where $x'$ is the unknown maximum extension, and in state $C$ it is $k(x')^2/2$ because it is now transferred to the spring. Equating the two we find $$x' = 2 x_0$$
   which is exactly twice of the equilibrium extension. Indeed, the mass oscillates between points $A$ and $C$ passing through the equilibrium point right at the middle.

Comment: So, in this case, can we say that the question is ambiguous? Shouldn't the question have specified if it wants the maximum extension or the mean extension?

Comment: The wording of the original question as  you gave it is not very clear. But if the question is about the "equilibrium" position, then your solution is correct. I would go back to the actual problem and read it again.

Comment: I have another question. In eqn (ii) of my post, the final potential energy $U_f = \frac{1}{2}kx^2-Mgx$. I am having trouble accepting this intuitively. Shouldn't the final potential energy be only $\frac{1}{2}kx^2$? What is that $Mgx$ term doing there?

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic You are writing the energy balance: the energy to extend the spring is $\frac12kx^2$ but you don't need to supply all of that energy yourself because an amount equal to  $Mgx$ comes from gravity. Your net expenditure is the difference.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the kinetic energy at the equilibrium position is not zero and if you are thinking that the object must be brought down very slowly then that is the different case because the thing which is absorbing its kinetic energy is doing **Negative Work**.

And in the second case if you just release the block freely then it will perform simple harmonic motion which includes kinetic energy as well.